# Program that converts character capitalization

Tags: c, function, if-statement, char, ascii

I'm making a program that, if the user inputs a lowercase character, generates its character in uppercase, and the opposite too. I'm using a function in order convert the character into lowercase or uppercase based on the `ASCII` table. Lowercase to uppercase is being converted correctly, but uppercase to lowercase is not.

```
char changeCapitalization(char n)
{
    //uppercase to lowercase
    if(n>=65 && n<=90)
        n=n+32;
    //lowercase to uppercase
    if(n>= 97 && n<=122)
        n=n-32;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: It looks like uppercase to lowercase is working... but then you're immediately checking if n is lowercase, which it is, and converting it back to uppercase.

Comment: it can be done as a one-liner `(n>='a' && n<='z' || n>='A' && n<= 'Z' ? n ^ 0x20 : n)`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: Using clever one-liners aren't necessarily a good idea for someone who is just learning the basics of programming.

Answer (score 2):

What the others are essentially saying is you want something like this ('else if' instead of 'if' on the lower to upper logic):

```
char changeCapitalization(char n)
{        
    if(n>=65 && n<=90) //uppercase to lowercase
        n=n+32;    
    else if(n>= 97 && n<=122) //lowercase to uppercase
        n=n-32;
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two `if` statements in sequence are executed - well - in sequence. So if you have an uppercase character, it will first be converted to lowercase, and afterwards, the next `if` statement will convert it back to lowercase. When you want to check the second condition only if the first one wasn't true, put `else` in front of the second `if`.

Also, rather than using the ASCII codes directly, you can compare characters to each other: `if (n >= 'A' && n <= 'Z')`.

Later, when you're more comfortable with programming and start doing bigger projects, you should use the language's built-in functions for working with strings and characters, such as `islower()` and `isupper()` - and if you need to support any non-English characters, you should read this [great article on the intricacies of encoding international characters](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 1):

Chang the line

```
if(n>= 97 && n<=122)
```

with

```
else if(n>= 97 && n<=122)
```

Because this condition is the opposite way like you said in the question